# To call 2 ajax functions on an onchange event

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want 3 ajax functions to be called simultaneously on an onchange event of a dropdown.

I tried like calling the 2nd function inside `if (xmlhttp1.readyState==4 &&     xmlhttp1.status==200)` of the 1st function and 3rd function inside `if (xmlhttp1.readyState==4 && xmlhttp1.status==200)` of the 2nd function.

But only the 1st function is called ,even second function is not called.
Any other ways to achieve it ?

Below are the functions:

```
function list1(ob){

    var id= ob;
    var xmlhttp1;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){//for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp1=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{//for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp1=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttp1.readyState==4 && xmlhttp1.status==200){
            alert("ajax1");
            list2(id);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp1.open("POST","/ajax/listSites.php",true);
    xmlhttp1.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
                              "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp1.send("id="+id);    
}


function list2(obb){

    var idd=obb;
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            alert("ajax2");
            list3(idd);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","/ajax/access_points_do_actions.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
                             "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.
        send("sel_system_id="+idd+
             "&action="+'LIST_SLAVE_FOR_ACCESS_POINT'); 

      }

// only alert ajax1 is displayed
```

Comment: Can you post what code you've tried so we can see where you're going wrong?

Comment: added he code, I had not weitten the 3 rd function, had written 2 functions

Comment: Sorry I meant the dropdown onchange code too.

Comment: onchange="list1(this.value);"  //this is dropdown onchange and first functions is called properly ie list1() is invoked properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just chain asynchronous calls like this:

```
onchange="Function1(); Function2();"
```

Update:

Your code:

```
<select id="se" onchange="javascript:list1(this.value); //this is current code
```

should be something like:

```
<select id="se" onchange="Javascript: list1(this); list1(this);">
```

Comment: should the functions be seperated by comas onchange="Function1(),Function2();"

Comment: No they should be executed as separate statements with semi-colons (;). Since they execute asynchronously the 2nd should execute when 1st finishes but is still waiting for result.

Comment: <select id="se" onchange="javascript:list1(this.value); //this is current code

Comment: You're welcome. Gave you a +1. Feel free to do the same for me :o)